# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints for Static table

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch, heightforrowatindexpath, swift2

I have a static table with two rows. First row has a switch. I want to enable second row only if the switch is turned on. And hide the row when switch is off.

The second row has label and textfield. They both have auto layout constraints.

I am hardcoding the height of second row as follows

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.section == 0 && !reminderSwitch.on {

        if indexPath.row == 1  {

            return 0.0

        }

    }

    return 44.0

}
```

Its doing what I want but I get following error/warning.

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.

I know instead of creating zero height row I can directly hide the row. But it leaves big empty space on the table. I don't want to do it that way. I want to create zero height row but I also want to remove the warning.

Comment: Why don't you add or remove the 2nd row when the switch changes value?

    `- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`

Comment: I just tried to do that. It throws an error. because this is static tableview you cannot insert new row.

Answer (score 0):

For static tables, your approach is correct. You just might need to check how you set up your constraints, and add some properties to change the value of some of those constraints.

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *_cellVerticalSpaceConstraint;
```

and

```
_cellVerticalSpaceConstraint.constant = 0;
```

In case you have dynamic cells, you can create a custom cell with a xib if you want or create it programatically. I would approach this scenario with a custom cell as you might want to capture the events of the the textfield and trigger other methods. There are plenty of examples like this:

https://medium.com/@musawiralishah/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722#.ukw4zn30o

To add / delete rows you can use the following code:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

insertIndexPaths & deleteIndexPaths are arrays of NSIndexPaths like the following :

```
NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0],
    nil];
```

Comment: All of these examples use dynamic prototype cell. I am using static cell. There is no way for updating table. Create a static tableview & try to insert empty row. It will throw error.

Comment: I've updated my answer to support the static table scenario

Comment: I tried it your way by setting constraint constant to 0 & back to its original value. But I still get error.

Comment: I assume you tied the constraint outlet in IB to the constraint in your xib, right?

Comment: Its static cell no xib. I tried every possible combination I can think of. I used constraint.active bool, I tried to set its hidden bool. I tried to align everything vertically in the centre of the cell. My app is doing the appropriate behaviour. I only get warning at the bottom. App execution does not stop. You should really test it yourself before posting answer.

Comment: Well, I don't see a lot of people trying to help you. I'm sorry my answer didn't work out. I understand your frustration, buy you should show some appreciation instead of what you posted on your last comment.
Feel free to downvote my answer

Comment: Like you said I would its frustrating & I would like to show appreciation when the problem is solved. This is not about trying your best. Its a bool like true or false. Either you solve my problem or you don't. That will decide where to appreciate your help or not.